# Apache subdomain redirects to WordPress on www

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I am running 2 websites on the same server:

- `www.example.com` `example.com` - WordPress
- `sub.example.com` - another site

Requesting `http://sub.example.com` should of course respond with the index for that website. Instead it redirects to `http://www.example.com` unless I explicitly request `http://sub.example.com/index.html`, in which case I get the correct website.

I think the issue may be WordPress's .htaccess file for permalinks (generated by WordPress):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Here are my VirtualHost conf files for both sites:

```
# sub.mysite.com
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sub
    ServerName sub.example.com

    <Directory /var/www/sub/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</Directory>

# www.example.com example.com
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com

    <Directory /var/www/wordpress/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was just my browser caching a permanent redirect from `sub` to `www`, which was probably the result of an improper configuration that I fixed before.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your server IP after

```
 <VirtualHost 12.345.56.789:80>
 ServerName sub.example.com
 DocumentRoot "/var/www/sub"
 <Directory /var/www/sub>
     Allow from all
     AllowOverride All
 </Directory> </VirtualHost>
```